# Prove if $x<y$ then $x+z<y+z$

Tags: induction, arithmetic, axioms, peano-axioms

**Note** I am looking a proof using Peano's axiom as I am working on the Natural Numbers, not the Real Numbers.

I need help proving "For each x,y,z in N, if $x<y$ then $x+z<y+z$

This must be done using Peano's axioms and the definitions of addition, multiplication, and ordering.

I have tried induction on z, and the base case works out but I run into an issue when it comes to the inductive part seeing as I am no longer dealing with equality.

I think induction is the correct way to approach this proof, however I become stuck once I reach a certain point in the proof.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question - this for $\mathbb N$ using Peano axioms, which is quite a different exercise.

Comment: If you're using Peano axioms, the only tool you really have (at least to begin with) is induction. Remember, $x<y$ if and only if there exists $w\in\mathbb N$ with $w\neq0$ and $y=x+w$.

Comment: Yes, Jason I have gotten that far and I have gotten to the point where I assume x + z < y + z (by the induction hypothesis), and also that by definition of order there exists some n ∈ N such that y + z = (x + z) + n.

Comment: Have you seen proofs for commutativity and associativity of addition?

Comment: Yes those have been proved.

Comment: You may be a classmate of Charlene, who's asking the same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1514718