# For each $x,y,z∈\mathbb N$, if $x<y$ then $x+z<y+z$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, order-theory, peano-axioms

For each $x,y,z∈\mathbb{N}$, if $x<y$ then $x+z<y+z$

I know how to solve this if it was $x=y$ then $x+z=y+z$ (which my professor said I need to do)
Is there a definition that says I can change the $<$ into a $=$ and then change it back to $<$ at the end?

I have a paper full of Peano's axioms that I'm able to build off of but I don't know what one I should be using.

Would For each $x,y∈\mathbb{N}$, $x<y$ or $x=y$ or $x>y$ 
be able to be used to change the $<$ to $=$?

Comment: How is "$<$" defined?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If x<y we say That there exist a k in N such that y=x+k

Comment: Do you have associativity and commutativity of addition available already? If so, can you show that $y=x+k$ implies $y+z=(x+z)+k$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes.

Comment: Same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513835

Comment: You gave in your post this link: `http://file:///C:/Users/Charlene/SkyDrive/Documents/302%20Project%201.pdf` For obvious reasons, this link will not work (Well, perhaps it will work for you, but not for people which do not sit at your computer.) The question is, in my opinion, understandable without that file, but it might be worth correcting anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) include, that $N$ contains $0$.

You said in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514718/for-each-x-y-z%E2%88%88-mathbb-n-if-xy-then-xzyz#comment3084985_1514718) that you define $x<y$ as $(\exists k\in N) y=x+k$. If we include zero, this would mean $x<x$. So I assume that you meant
$$
\begin{align*}
x\le y &\Leftrightarrow (\exists k\in N) x+k=y\\
x<y &\Leftrightarrow (\exists k\in N) x+S(k)=y
\end{align*}
$$

If you have $x\le y$, that means that $x+k=y$ for some $k$. From this you get:
$$(x+z)+k = x+(z+k) = x+(k+z) = (x+k)+z = y+z$$
which means $x+z\le y+z$. (Note that we have used associativity and commutativity; so this works if you have shown these properties before.)

The proof that $x<y$ implies $x+z<y+z$ is similar. (Just replace $k$ by $S(k)$.)

This is basically just more detailed version of the approach suggested in [Hagen von Eitzen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514718/for-each-x-y-z%E2%88%88-mathbb-n-if-xy-then-xzyz#comment3085009_1514718).

Answer (score 0):

If it is peano it is fairly simple, let $\sigma$ denote our "next" function such that by definition we have $a+1=\sigma(a)$. By definition of $x<y$ we have that $y=\sigma^n(x)$ for some $n$ where it denotes iterative application of $\sigma$. Then we have that $y+z=\sigma^{m}(y)=\sigma^{m+n}(x)=\sigma^n(x+z)$ which implies that $y+z>x+z$, by definition of how the next-function works and addition.

Comment: i don't think i can use the sigma to an n or m power because i have yet learned anything about powers.

Comment: If you're dealing with Peanos axioms the $\sigma$ is the function in peanos axioms from which it is constructed.